# How to fix Discord OAuth2 returning "Invalid 'code' in request'"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, oauth, discord.js

I'm currently trying to build an authentication app however I keep getting `Invalid "code" in request` when trying to get a refresh token from the code discord provided.

Here's a snapshot of my request:

```
const response = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        client_id: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID as string,
        client_secret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        scope: 'identify email'
    }).toString()
})
```

I'm using exactly the same scopes, redirect uri and code. I have ensured that my credentials are correct and the JSON returned is `{ error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Invalid "code" in request.' }`

What's the solution to this? Many thanks.

Comment: For any of you trying to refer to duplicate questions:
+ Using JSON body changes the problem entirely
+ Not adding `scopes` in the body doesn't get rid of the error
+ Using "client_credentials" does not return the refresh token.

Comment: Do not dislike a question without answering or stating your reason. This question is not a duplicate and clearly states the issue.

Comment: Have you made sure to configure the URI you're passing as the `redirectURI` in the application's Discord Developer Portal?

Comment: As I have already mentioned in the question, everything has been configured and is identical.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `auhorization_code`. Should be `authorization_code`.

Comment: Despite fixing this, now it is constantly returning `invalid "code" in request".

Comment: Can you show us how `code` is being defined?